# React Native - upload image to Firebase using @react-native-firebase/storage - No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I am getting the following error when uploading an image to Firebase:

> Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()

Here is my code:

1. App.js

   ```
   import * as Firebase from 'firebase';

   componentDidMount() {
       Firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   }
   ```
2. Profile.js

   ```
   import * as Firebase from 'firebase';
   import rnFb from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

   uploadImage = localUri =>
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       const localUri2 = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? localUri.replace('file://', '') : localUri;
       const fbUri = Firebase.storage().ref();
       rnFb().ref(localUri2).putFile(fbUri)
       .then(
           () => { resolve(); }
       )
       .catch(
           (e) => { reject(e); }
       );
   });
   ```

It's failing at the `.putFile` line.

I don't understand what the problem is because I am calling `.initializeApp()` in `App.js`

**UPDATE 12/21**
I added `console.log(Firebase.apps.length);` right before `rnFb().ref(localUri2).putFile(fbUri)` and the output is 1...very strange indeed.

...and if I do exactly as the error asks and call `firebase.initializeApp()` right before `rnFb().ref(localUri2).putFile(fbUri)` I get the error Error:

```
Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists
```

Help!!

Comment: Put some debug logging in your code.  Is initializeApp being called first?

Comment: Yes indeed it is being called first

Comment: Please provide versions of RN and RN Firebase you're using. The recommended way of initializing the app, is to provide a [`google-services.json`](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/quick-start/android-firebase-credentials) file for Android and [`GoogleService-Info.plist`](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/quick-start/ios-firebase-credentials) for iOS. Also make sure you have Storage API enabled on Firebase console.

Comment: "react-native": "0.61.5", "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^6.0.4",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the Firebase SDK used internally inside `@react-native-firebase` is independent of the ordinary Firebase SDK from `firebase`.

It can be exposed using:

```js
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
// OR
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/storage';
```

Applying these changes (and simplifying your code), leaves you with the following:

```js
import storage, { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

// can possibly be somewhere else
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

uploadImage = localUri => {
  const localUri2 = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? localUri.replace('file://', '') : localUri;
  return storage().ref('/path/to/upload/to').putFile(localUri2)
}
```

Rather than use ["client initialization"](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/app/quick-start/#client-initialization) using `firebase.initializeApp()`, you can also use "native initialization"
 for [Android](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/quick-start/android-firebase-credentials) and [iOS](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/quick-start/ios-firebase-credentials).

Comment: 2 questions if I may.  (1) are you saying I need to run firebase.initializeApp() twice....once for @react-native-firebase/storage and a second time for regular firebase (database and auth)?  (2) how do I get the string 'path to upload to'

Comment: 1) You shouldn't be using the native Firebase SDK at all. Use the same Firebase SDK loaded by `@react-native-firebase`. 2) `/path/to/upload/to` is just a placeholder for wherever in your storage you want to save your file. Let's say these were profile pictures, you could save the image as `profile-pics/someUserId.png`. It's up to you what you call the file and where you store it.

Comment: I use the native Firebase SDK for realtime database and auth all over my app. If I abandon the native Firebase SDK for the @react-native-firebase SDK.......will I need to rewrite all my code?

Comment: @jamesmurphy No, it **should** just be a one-line swap between wherever you use `import * as Firebase from 'firebase';` to `import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/app';` - although you might need to change `Firebase` to `firebase` or use `{ firebase: Firebase }`. Is there a particular reason for avoiding `@react-native-firebase/database`? I would have thought porting everything across to observables would be beneficial?

Comment: I see your point.  Did you see the answer from @adrianpascu?  He raises a valid point that theres nowhere in the docs it says you need to manually call `initializeApp().  I do find it odd that you need to call this function when all the options (i.e. api key etc) are in the google-services.json file.

Comment: I also covered that in my answer as the last paragraph, albeit I glossed over it assuming that you had already tried it. Have you tried following those instructions to see if you've missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the API documentation? I can't seem to find anywhere in the docs that you need to manually call `initializeApp()`

Answer (score -1):

I think your `fbUri` is wrong. The param has to be a string.
For ex:

```js
    firebase
          .storage()
          .ref('remote_path') // remote path where you want to store
          .putFile(
            'local/ok.jpeg' // local file
          )
          .then(successCb)
          .catch(failureCb);
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work....I ran toString() method on fbUri to get the full path....but still same error

Comment: @jamesmurphy toString() is not the right way. You have to get the local path of the file.